# Not able to resize UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I've converted my app from Iphone to universal. Everything is fine but I am unable to resize my view. I changed UIViewController size to (768,1024), but it's view size is restricted to 975 and I am not able to change it. First two screen shots are UIViewController's settings. Third screen shot is for UIViewController's view. How can I solve this problem?

[image: UIViewController Settings]

[image: UIViewController Settings]

[image: Issue in UIView resizing]

Comment: did you use two storyboard?

Comment: Yes I did. One for Iphone and other is for Ipad

Comment: You must have a opaque TabBar (49 pts) at the bottom. No in your view controller but inferred from previous.